# How to make text appear underneath when pressing on a sentence

Tags: html

In my FAQ-form I have some questions and some answers. When you press on the question, which is a blue link, I want it to appear a text underneath that gives the answer to that question.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Please give an example of some effort made to solve this  yourself.

Comment: Do some research into Javascript.  You can make something easy using jQuery, but you'll need to do the research yourself to find what works for your application.

Comment: I have no clue on how to solve this..Dont you think I would post it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap and use their "Collapse".

Very easy to put into your site, and easy to maintain. You also get support for tabs etc:

http://jsfiddle.net/ubuu77b4/

[image]

Example code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Click me to see
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Click me too!!!
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Put this in your `head`:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works very good thank you. What does the `head`-section do?

Comment: In your HTML you have some code that must be there: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`In the `<head>` you put information that the browser needs etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I change the frame where the "Click me too!!!" is located in? I only want it to be highlighted blue as a link. Thank you.

Comment: Also how can I make it so that the questions are always closed :)? As it is now the first question is always open. see this [link](http://www.coolstuff.se/page/faq)

Comment: Remove the class `in` from the first one: See here http://jsfiddle.net/ubuu77b4/1/  - Like this: `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse"` - in stead of `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"`

Comment: Wonderful, was there a way to do this with a blue link texts as the link I posted? Thank you.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ubuu77b4/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69259/discussion-between-joneskvist-and-preben).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.question').find('.answer').toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.question {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}
.answer {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Question 1</a>
    <div class="answer">
        This is the answer to Question 1
    </div>
</div><br/><br/>
<div class="question">
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Question 2</a>
    <div class="answer">
        This is the answer to Question 2
    </div>
</div><br/><br/>
<div class="question">
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Question 3</a>
    <div class="answer">
        This is the answer to Question 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Where can I paste the first code?

Comment: you can paste it in `<javascript>` tags in your html page or you can place it in a javascript file. so long as you make sure that you include a reference to jquery version 1.11 or higher in your html page.

Comment: How can I add these javascript tags?